# Android Network Changes Event

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am working on one application where I need to implement one functionality. If user is connected to Wifi, I want to disconnect Wifi and connect him to Mobile Internet.

I have implemented all functions which ON/OFF Wifi and ON/OFF Mobile Data but I want when I turn Wifi off and turn mobile data ON and maximum timeout period will be 20 seconds. It should only listen for max 20 seconds that user is connected to mobile data or not after mobile data ON request is sent.

Comment: you can use one another thread, and sleep that for 20 sec then check the mobile data and if that is Enabled then send data, else warning to user or anything you want

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to check for connected connection either WIFI or MOBILE

```
 public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
    {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
        boolean connectionavailable = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();


        NetworkInfo informationabtnet = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo)
        {
            try
            {

            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
            if(informationabtnet.isAvailable()&&informationabtnet.isConnected())
                connectionavailable = true;
                Log.i("ConnectionAvailable", ""+connectionavailable);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Inside utils catch clause , exception is"+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

Using this method you will get to know on which network your mobile phone is connected and you can perform your desired operation.

Run this statement when you turn off your WIFI. This statement will execute after 20 seconds do whatever you want here

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

//TODO this statement will execute after 20 seconds
                        }
                    }, 1 * 20 * 1000);
```